# Unable to overwrite local variable in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a dropdown using a dynamic list of items returned from a function call in Typescript but I am having trouble with overwriting the variables defined in the code and constantly getting their initial values as return.

I manage to read the value of dropdown items as returned by the function just fine but am unable to assign those values to the dropdown items parameter. Here´s my code:

```
let tempList: myObject[] = []; //unable to overwrite

const myComponent = () => {

  let dropdownItems=[{label: ""}]; //unable to overwrite
  
  fetchAllDropdownItems().then((x)=> tempList = x).catch((err)=> console.log(err))

  //Converting myObject array to a neutral array
  myList.forEach((y)=> dropdownItems.push(y))

  console.log(tempList) // returns [{label: "A"}, {label: "B"}]
  console.log(dropdownItems)// returns [{label: ""}, {label: "A"}, {label: "B"}]

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={dropdownItems} // results in initial value of dropdownItems i.e {label: ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

And here´s how myObject looks like:

```
export interface myObject {
    label: string;
}
```

Previously I had defined items in my dropdown as `items={[{ label: "A" }, {label: "B"}]}` which is essentially the same structure as what I am getting from `fetchAllDropdownItems`-function return but my goal is to not hard code the items.

I need help in figuring out why I am unable to overwrite variables and would appreciate any advice/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make the api call inside `useEffect()` and also define `dropdownItems` as a state inside your component. Otherwise, you will not get the updated list rendered on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that you aren't updating `tempList`, it's that your component renders before you do and nothing tells it to re-render because you're not using that list as state.

With the code structure you've shown, you have two options:

1. Make your entire module wait until you've fetched the list from the server, before even exporting your component, by using [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) (a stage 3 proposal well on its way to stage 4 ["finished"] with good support in modern bunders)

   or
2. Have your component re-render once the list is received

Here's an example of #1:

```typescript
const dropdownItems: myObject[] = await fetchAllDropdownItems();
// top-level await −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^

const myComponent = () => {

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={dropdownItems}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

Note, again, that it loads the items **once** then reuses them, loading them when this module is loaded. That means that it may load the items even if your component is never actually used.

There are a bunch of different ways you can spin #2.

Here's one of them:

```typescript
const dropdownItems: Promise<myObject[]> = fetchAllDropdownItems();

const myComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<myObject[] | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    dropdownItems
      .then(items => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setItems(items);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/display error loading items...
      });
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={items || []}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

That loads the items proactively as soon as your module is loaded, and so like #1 it will load them even if your component is never used, but that means the items are (probably) there and ready to be used when your component is first used.

But the "probably" in the last paragraph is just that: The fetch may still be unsettled before your component is used. That's why the component uses the promise. That means that in that example your component will always render twice: Once blank, then again with the list. It'll be fairly quick, but it will be twice. Making it happen just once if the items are already loaded is possible, but markedly complicates the code:

```typescript
let dropdownItems: myObject[] | null = null;
const dropdownItemsPromise: Promise<myObject[]>
    = fetchAllDropdownItems().then(items => {
      dropdownItems = items;
      return items;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // ...handle/display error loading items...
    });

const myComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<myObject[] | null>(dropdownItems);
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    if (items === null) {
      dropdownItemsPromise.then(items => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setItems(items);
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [items]);
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={items || []}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

Or you might want to wait to load the items until the first time your component is used:

```typescript
let dropdownItems: myObject[] | null = null;

const myComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<myObject[] | null>(dropdownItems);
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    if (items === null) {
      fetchAllDropdownItems().then(items => {
        dropdownItems = items;
        if (!unmounted) {
          setItems(items);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          // ...handle/display error loading items...
        }
      });
    }
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [items]);
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={items || []}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

Or you might want to load the items *every* time the component is used (perhaps they change over time, or the component is rarely used and caching them in the code seems unnecessary):

```typescript
const myComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<myObject[] | null>(dropdownItems);
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    fetchAllDropdownItems().then(items => {
      if (!unmounted) {
        setItems(items);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (!unmounted) {
        // ...handle/display error loading items...
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [items]);
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Dropdown
          items={items || []}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e?.value)
          }}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```